# Recording history of ranks

Tags: mysql, rank

Once per day, this is being executed to rank everyone in the database based on `points`.

```
    SET @r=0;
    UPDATE ranks SET previousRank=rank, rank= @r:= (@r+1) ORDER BY points DESC;
```

The field `previousRank` contains their previous rank. However, we are now wanting to record the **history** of the rank.

If we change `previousRank` to a STRING, is it possible to modify the query to append "rank," to the end of field `previousRank` instead of replace it? For example, it would look like this: `21,22,20,18,24,`.

If so, how would this be done, and are there any steps that can be taken to remove the end comma without slowing the query?

Comment: Why don't you store the history in a different table? Or in the same table by adding a date column to the key? This is the relational way to solve this problem. Storing multiple values separated by commas in one field is asking for problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `previousRank` to end with a comma

```
SET @r=0;
UPDATE ranks SET
    previousRank=CONCAT(previousRank,rank,','),
    rank= @r:= (@r+1)
    ORDER BY points DESC
;
```

If you do not want `previousRank` to end with a comma

```
SET @r=0;
UPDATE ranks SET
    previousRank=IF(previousRank='',rank,CONCAT(previousRank,',',rank)),
    rank= @r:= (@r+1)
    ORDER BY points DESC
;
```

**Give it a Try !!!**